# Curl version of this function?

Tags: php, curl

Hi `fsockopen` has been disabled for me, but `curl` isn't.
Please can someone translate this to `curl` version? I have tried but got stumped.

```
$sock = fsockopen("http://facebook.com" , 80); 
if(FALSE == $sock ) {
    echo "Ms Here"; 
    return;
  }

fwrite($sock, $header ); 
while ($line = fread($sock, 25000)){
    echo $line;
}

fclose($sock);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://facebook.com"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: close'));
$response = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks, but what of the while loop, fwrite?

Comment: you wont need to do that, since you will get the response in $response